# Семантика глагола 'будет' в конце предложения

Tags: семантика, глаголы

Одна из аудиозаписей речи Толстого заканчивается словами:

> Прощайте, будет.

Простой вопрос: какова семантика «будет» в данном контексте? Что «будет»?

Answer (score 1):

В стихотворении А. Плещеева идёт перечень просьб детворы старику-леснику: «Много их сбегалось к деду вечерком; / Щебетали, словно птички перед сном: / "Дедушка, голубчик, сделай мне свисток! / Дедушка, найди мне беленький грибок! / Ты хотел мне нынче сказку рассказать! / Посулил ты белку, дедушка, поймать!"»

В ответ им было сказано: «Ладно, ладно, детки, дайте только срок, / Будет вам и белка, будет и свисток!»

Повторяющийся глагол — часть этой крылатой фразы — обещание на прощанье преимущественно доброго и приятного.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ну, будет вам = Ну, полно вам = Ну, достаточно вам = Ну, хватит вам 
Прощайте, будет = Прощайте, уже оно будет вам = Прощайте, хватит вам
```

> Что «будет»?

Как видно из примеров: всё, что вас не удовлетворяет - будет. То есть его уже хватит, оно будет, и пора простить/проститься уже.

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные версии *расшифровки* слов Л. Н. Толстого (продолжительность — всего 34 секунды; особенности — выделены мной).

[**1.**](http://www.ognikuzbassa.ru/category-publicism/357-starik-govoril-vam-dobro) Спасибо, ребята, что ходите ко мне. Я рад, когда вы хорошо учитесь. Только, пожалуйста, не шалите. **А** то есть такие, что не **слушают**, а только сами шалят. А то, что я вам говорю, **нужно** для вас будет. Вы **вспомните**, когда уж меня не будет, что старик говорил **вам** добро. Прощайте, будет.

[**2.**](https://dzen.ru/media/id/5e4f07d3b891b40f5a187ae4/u-nas-est-vozmojnost-uslyshat-golos-lva-tolstogo-600fce15052efe27dfa3fb34) **Я…** Спасибо, ребята, что ходите ко мне. Я рад, когда вы хорошо учитесь. Только, пожалуйста, не шалите. **А** то есть такие, что не **слушают**, а только сами шалят. А то, что я вам говорю, **нужным** для вас будет. Вы **помните**, когда уж меня не будет, что старик говорил **нам** добро.
Прощайте, будет... [в конце — многоточие]

**3.** Спасибо, ребята, что ходите ко мне. Я рад, когда вы хорошо учитесь. Только, пожалуйста, не шалите, **а** то есть такие, что не **слушаются**, а только сами шалят. А то, что я вам говорю, **нужно** для вас будет. Вы **вспомните**, когда уж меня не будет, что старик говорил **вам** добро. Прощайте, будет.

Мне *кажется*, что речь Толстого ***просто обрывается*** на полуфразе (можно послушать во второй ссылке), что в ней нет никакого **особенного** значения слова "быть" (будет), а имеется обычная недосказанность (по техническим причинам столетней давности).